# How to call public async Task Method() from a Thread calling in asp.net core C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I want to call a public async Task Method() from a Thread calling in asp.net core C#. But while calling getting an error message.

Following async Task method:

```
public async Task PaymentCheck()
{
   try{
     var result = _context.BillPayment.Where(d => d.PaymentStatus == 2).ToList();
     var resultdata = await _pendingPaymentActions.InprogressPaymentCheck(111);
   }
   catch(Exception ex){}  
   
}
```

Now I want to call the above method By Thread calling:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PaymentCheck)); 
backgroundThread.Start();
```

But getting error: **"PaymentCheck() has the wrong return type"**

Comment: If you need PaymentCheck to be run on a background thread, use `Task.Run()` instead of creating your own threads. Realistically you should ask yourself if you really need to run it on a separate thread, or if just running it async is enough. Generally speaking, creating your own threads in `Asp.Net core` is a bad idea.

Comment: Don't use `Thread` to begin with. It's unsafe and can easily throw exceptions because it tries to use objects that were disposed when the action terminated. If you want to start a long-running job use either BackgroundService or a scheduler like HangFire, Coravel or Quartz.net. The web server knows nothing about that thread either, so it can't signal it to complete gracefully when the app pool recycles

Comment: Use `ToListAsync()` instead of `ToList()` to avoid blocking while waiting for the database to respond

Comment: BTW I suspect you already found out that this thread throws exceptions, so you tried to cover them up with `catch{}`. That doesn't work though. There's *no* guarantee that the thread will even start, much less run to completion,before the data it uses gets disposed

Comment: Please don't `catch(Exception ex){}`. At least log the exception somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I do not think calling async Task method in a separate thread in asp.net core is a good approach, you just need to call the method with `await` keyword, for example...

```
   public async Task PaymentCheck()
    {
       try{
         var result = await _context.BillPayment.Where(d => d.PaymentStatus == 2).ToListAsync();
         //Use ToListAsync() instead of ToList() to avoid blocking while waiting for the database to respond
         var resultdata = await _pendingPaymentActions.InprogressPaymentCheck(111);
       }
       catch(Exception ex){}  
       
    }
```

call it...

`await PaymentCheck();` // as there is no return type

Also, don't eat the exception at least write it in logs.

Comment: You should change the first line to `await ...ToListAsync();`

Comment: I didn't. I just *up*voted. That `catch{}` is ugly but that's what the original question contains too. You forgot `await` in the first line. Neither is a reason to downvote.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , you have shown normal calling process, but I want to know the process by Thread calling. It should run in  Background by different Thread calling so that the user is not to wait for User Interface. The User should work as usual and Background Thread will continue its operations of its own.